# GCC Segmentation fault for this structured binding using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, c++17, structured-bindings

I got a segmentation fault for this code in GCC but compiles fine with MSVC

```
QMap<int, QPair<QString, QString>> someData; 
// inserting some value
for (auto id : someData.keys()) {
   auto [foo, bar] = someData[id];
   //do stuff with foo, bar.
}
```

And the structured binding emits a segfault.

Log:

```
internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

Solution

declare the structured binding as reference.

```
auto& [foo, bar] = someData[id];
```

It looks like GCC cannot deduce the qualifiers, since operator[] returns a T&.

Comment: Can you attach a GDB error log + stack trace? Not sure how you expect someone to solve this without at least that information.

Comment: @Botje edited. This is the only log I have access to.

Comment: Oh, you actually crashed the compiler? Well done! What version of GCC is this?

Comment: @Botje thank you! its gcc-7.3.0. On the other hand... why am I getting downvoted?

Comment: Does it happen with a newer GCC, if you can test that? It may have already been solved.

Comment: @Botje I will be able to test it later. But for now, i found a solution, edited the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a compiler bug report, not a question.